# An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0xaa722d0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

**Update:** -[NSIndexPath row]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x895fe70

When I run my app on device and Analyze it says:

> An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0xaa722d0.

It's showing an error at:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row]: -1;
```

---

I am very new to Objective C programming and have been struggling with the below issue since two days, I recently created an app using Xcode 3.2.6 but upgraded to Xcode 4 two days back and now facing memory deallocation issues in my below code. I researched on using instruments and enabled zombie and understood where the problem is occurring but just not able to resolve it, 
I request some guidance please.. below is my code being run in Xcode 4.2.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [list count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CheckMarkCellIdentifier = @"CheckMarkCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             CheckMarkCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CheckMarkCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.accessoryType = (row == oldRow && lastIndexPath != nil) ? 
    UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int newRow = [indexPath row];
    int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row]: -1;

    //----Captures the value selected in the list and shown in parent view.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SchneiderBMSAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SchneiderBMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.priorityValue = cell.textLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"Product selected is: %@",appDelegate.priorityValue);

    if (newRow != oldRow)
    {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                                    indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
                                    lastIndexPath]; 
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        lastIndexPath = indexPath;

    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.list = nil;
    self.lastIndexPath = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)dealloc {
   [list release];
    [lastIndexPath release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: please update your question with error description using BT command in GDB.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, the simple addition of a [obj retain] call should fix it.

Comment: Run Analyze in Xcode. What/where is the problem? In the console what is the error message?

Comment: @RRB, CodaFi and CocoaFu - Thank you much for your quick response! I just posted the error I am getting, would that be helpful?

Comment: @CodaFi, can you kindly elaborate how to do [obj retain] ? thank you..

Comment: Sorry, wrong code, call "lastIndexPath = [[[NSIndexPath alloc]init(With)...]retain];"

Comment: @CodaFi: I tried accordingly, THANK YOU SO MUCH!! it helped!! it works  now :)   I replaced  the line lastIndexPath = indexPath;  with      lastIndexPath = [indexPath retain];

Comment: No problem.  New, retain, and copy, are your friends in these kinds of situations.

Comment: Will surely keep that in mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that when `lastIndexPath` is released, it will become nil. That isn't so. You either need to retain the object (preferably by using a setter rather than setting the instance variable directly) or not store a reference to it.

Comment: Chuck, It worked!! :) thank you so much! as suggested I replaced the line:  lastIndexPath = indexPath;   With this ->               lastIndexPath = [indexPath retain];

Answer (score 0):

I had an app that used nearly the same code (can't recall which tutorial I referenced) that I completed in iOS 4.3 but did not release to the App Store.  Had the exact same issue when I recently revived the app and tried to run it in iOS 5.  I was able to get it to work by changing the line:

lastIndexPath = indexPath;

to

self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;

And then it worked fine in iOS 5. I guess it accomplishes the same thing as Chuck recommended by retaining the object.  But why did iOS 5 care and not iOS 4.3???  Could it be due to ARC in iOS 5?

Comment: Am a novice myself, but I am guessing iOS 5 does the memory management for us, while in iOS 4.3, we had to take care of managing the memory which made me put that piece of code in 4.3.  Just my two cents..